# push_back an array into a matrix c++

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, vector

I need to insert an array of 10 elements in a matrix or vector of rows growing. What I would do is to enter the array as a row of the matrix of size `n x 10`. For the matrix push each array should then grow by 1 line. For each step of the iteration matrix will be:

> [ 1 ] [ 10 ].. [ 2 ] [ 10 ] .. [ 3 ] [ 10 ]

I'm using `std::array<int 10>` for the construction of array.

Comment: Have you try something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following container `std::vector<std::array<int, 10>>`

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <array>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    const size_t N = 10;
    std::vector<std::array<int, N>> matrix;

    matrix.push_back( { { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 } } );

    for ( const auto &row : matrix )
    {
        for ( int x : row ) std::cout << std::setw( 2 ) << x << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }        

    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::array<int, N> a = { { 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19 } }; 
    matrix.push_back( a );

    for ( const auto &row : matrix )
    {
        for ( int x : row ) std::cout << std::setw( 2 ) << x << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }        
}
```

The program output is

```
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 

 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 
10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
```

Answer (score -1):

One possible solution if I understood your problem well:

```
std::vector<std::vector<T>> my_matrix;
....
std::array<T,10> my_array;
...
std::vector<T> temp;
temp.reserve(10);
std::copy(std::begin(my_array),std::end(my_array),std::back_insertor(temp));
my_matrix.emplace_back(std::move(temp));
```

or even better:

```
std::vector<std::vector<T>> my_matrix;
....
std::array<T,10> my_array;
...
my_matrix.emplace_back(std::begin(my_array),std::end(my_array));
```

Comment: perfect! works fine. Now i've to convert my matrix to mat for recall Set up training data in SVM (opencv). Can you help me? The object that SVM use is: Mat trainingDataMat(4, 2, CV_32FC1, trainingData);

Comment: can i use this code?  'cv::Mat matMatrix.rows; ++i)
      for(int j=0; j<matMatrix.cols; ++j)
       matMatrix.at<double>(i, j) = matrix.at(i).at(j);'